# Azure app service(.Net web api deployed) to access azure sql using managed identity

Tags: azure

I have a azure app service(.Net web api was deployed) that wants to access azure sql using managed identity. I enable system managed identity in app service.
I created a azure AD `group(TestEnvGroup)` and added members as app service managed identity, few users in it. In azure sql server, i configured one sql admin to set as admin.

**In sql server i created the user and assigned the roles as below:
**

```
CREATE USER [TestEnvGroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER; 
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [TestEnvGroup];
```

After that my app service can successfully access the azure sql using managed identity without having any issue.

**
There is one issue here:**

If i removed the managed identity from the azure AD group, still my app service can be able to access sql server even after i restarted my app service and waited for more than 24 hrs for cache clearing, but still my app service can be able to access azure sql.
And also with regards to sql server, i have not removed user and roles assigned to that azure ad group.
If i removed the user and roles assogned to that group, app service will not work, but am expecting the same behavior when i removed the managed identity from azure ad group.

Please requesting you to give the suggestions?

Expecting resolution:

> 1. Should not access azure app service to sql server, when managed identity is removed from the azure ad group
> 2. Removing Azure Ad group as a user from the sql server is working fine for me by preventing app service to access sql server, same
>    behavior i should get it in removing identity from azure ad level
> 3. I tried to restart the app service with many attempts but no use